# Regular Expression in the ASP.NET Validator control

Tags: asp.net, regex

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="can not use this password" 
Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
ValidationExpression="(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n]).*$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

What does the ValidationExpression `"(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n]).*$"` look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It validates that the password is at least eight characters in length, containing at least one number or special character.

This expression might be better for password strength:

```
ValidationExpression="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"
```

The above expression will validate that the password contains:

- at least one (1) upper case letter
- at least one (1) lower case letter
- at least one (1) number or special character
- at least eight (8) characters in length

Answer (score 0):

You need a regular expression decoder. Try your regular expression here....

http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be looking for a password that must be at least 8 characters long, consists of at least one letter, number, or special character (excluding white space characters).